# Npm does not work correctly after installing packages

Tags: npm

I have strange problem with npm. After installing some packages (last one was angular-cli), package does not work. The installation went well, but when I try check version of angular-cli (ng -v), console give me an error, that ng is does not know. It does not matter if I install packages locally or globally, everytime the same problem.
I tried to uninstall node.js and install again, but it does not work.

Other thing what I do not understand is X:/ path when I open commands line. When I open commands line as Administrator, everything is great. What I also noticed, in C partition I have a folder "~." and when I install some packages, this packages are installed in this folder. I think this is the reason, why this packages are invisible after installing. But I do not know why and how to fix this.

Comment: I could be wrong but when you install a package such as angular you don't have ability to call it trough a console like that as its not installed on the system level but in your node_modules.. Is this what is happening to you?

Comment: It is true. Packages are installed in path : C:/~./node modules/... . Even when I install packages globally, packages are always there. I tried install packages in Visual Studio Code, but problem also occurs.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, you are not able to run comment that you are trying to run such as ng -v because your terminal doesn't know what that is

Comment: So what should I do? Add path to angular-cli manually in environment variables?
And everytime stay problem with this strange path C:/~./node modules/...

Comment: I am not sure I don't use angular but it must be in documentation on the website.. Did you have a chance to read it?

Comment: Not yet. I will try to search something in free time.